# Routes of mvc and api projects conflict

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a .NET Core project which includes MVC and a Web API in the same solution. I'm trying to connect those projects to each other but API's route and MVC's conflict.

I have an a tag like this,

```
<a asp-controller="Categories" asp-action="Update" 
   class="btn btn-primary" asp-route-categoryId="@category.Id">Update</a>
```

then this a tag generates a link like this

```
href="/api/Categories?categoryId=1"
```

My controllers and actions are using same names, I think that's why it happens, so I've changed the names then it worked. I can change the names but wonder why this happens. Are there different solutions?

Comment: What hrefs do  you want for api and for mvc applications? And what hrefs do you have now?

Comment: What do you mean `My controllers and actions are using same names`?Can you share your controller and action?

Comment: This a tag in a view what's in the mvc, this href must triggers action in mvc controller but as you see it goes api's action

Comment: For example I have categories controller in api and mvc and both of those controllers have Update action, in exactly the same structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one of the solutions could be using attribure routing. For example

api

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
public class CategoryController:ControllerBase
```

mvc

```
[Route("[controller]/[action]")]
public class CategoryController:Controller
```

or you can configure similar route templates in startup file.